# XSLT basic - Incorrect transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I just started to use XSLT and i can't proceed to create a very simple XSL
Here is my problem :
I have a basic xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <InvokeLIREVOIE xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2015-01-05T18:12:58+01:00" transLanguage="FR" baseLanguage="FR" messageID="1420477955208836965" maximoVersion="7 5 20140411-2000 V7511--1">
            <LIREVOIESet>
                <VOIE>
                <CODE_CATEGORIE></CODE_CATEGORIE>
                <CODE_COMMUNE>203</CODE_COMMUNE>
                <CODE_COMMUNE_ASSAIN></CODE_COMMUNE_ASSAIN>
                <CODE_COMMUNE_ASSAIN_INSEE></CODE_COMMUNE_ASSAIN_INSEE>
                <CODE_LIVRE></CODE_LIVRE>
                <CODE_VOIE>2985</CODE_VOIE>
                <COORDX></COORDX>
                <COORDY></COORDY>
                ... (more useless elements)
                </VOIE>
            </LIREVOIESet>
        </InvokeLIREVOIE>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The output after transformation has to be :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v01="http://host/WebServiceXXX"
xmlns:v011="http://host/WebServiceXXX">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <v01:enveloppeTechnique>
         <v01:horodateAppel>?</v01:horodateAppel>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v01:idOperation>?</v01:idOperation>
         <v01:idTransaction>?</v01:idTransaction>
         <v01:idConsommateur>SIV2</v01:idConsommateur>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v01:idUtilisateur>?</v01:idUtilisateur>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v01:canal>?</v01:canal>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v01:langue>?</v01:langue>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <v01:pays>?</v01:pays>
      </v01:enveloppeTechnique>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v011:lireVoie>
         <v011:CODE_COMMUNE>609</v011:CODE_COMMUNE>
         <v011:CODE_VOIE>7440</v011:CODE_VOIE>
      </v011:lireVoie>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Basically i just have to copy CODE_COMMUNE and CODE_VOIE values from my main xml file to my output.
The others fields can be static

I created a very basic XSL to do so but i have a weird output and i can't find what's wrong :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
203
2985
```

My XSL File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v01="http://host/WebServiceXXX" xmlns:v011="http://host/WebServiceXXX">
        <soapenv:Header>
          <v01:enveloppeTechnique>
                 <v01:horodateAppel></v01:horodateAppel>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <v01:idOperation></v01:idOperation>
                 <v01:idTransaction></v01:idTransaction>
                 <v01:idConsommateur>SIV2</v01:idConsommateur>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <v01:idUtilisateur></v01:idUtilisateur>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <v01:canal></v01:canal>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <v01:langue></v01:langue>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <v01:pays></v01:pays>
            </v01:enveloppeTechnique>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
          <v011:lireVoie>
            <xsl:template match="VOIE">
                <v011:CODE_COMMUNE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="CODE_COMMUNE"/>
                </v011:CODE_COMMUNE>
                <v011:CODE_VOIE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="CODE_VOIE" />
                </v011:CODE_VOIE>
            </xsl:template>
          </v011:lireVoie>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Please post your XSLT code so we can see what went wrong. The result you show suggests that none of your templates have been applied, and only the default template rules that copy text nodes have been invoked. Most likely a namespace issue.

Comment: Update post : XSL code and output @michael.hor257k thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues:

1. You must put your instructions *inside* a template in order to write
   to the output tree.
2. Your source XML elements are in namespaces; you must declare a
   prefix for each namespace  and use it when addressing a node in the
   source document.
3. You must use the `<comment>` instruction in order to place a comment
   in the output.

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
exclude-result-prefixes="max">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:v01="http://host/WebServiceXXX" xmlns:v011="http://host/WebServiceXXX">
        <soapenv:Header>
            <v01:enveloppeTechnique>
                 <v01:horodateAppel></v01:horodateAppel>
                 <xsl:comment>Optional:</xsl:comment>
                 <v01:idOperation></v01:idOperation>
                 <v01:idTransaction></v01:idTransaction>
                 <v01:idConsommateur>SIV2</v01:idConsommateur>
                 <xsl:comment>Optional:</xsl:comment>
                 <v01:idUtilisateur></v01:idUtilisateur>
                 <xsl:comment>Optional:</xsl:comment>
                 <v01:canal></v01:canal>
                 <xsl:comment>Optional:</xsl:comment>
                 <v01:langue></v01:langue>
                 <xsl:comment>Optional:</xsl:comment>
                 <v01:pays></v01:pays>
            </v01:enveloppeTechnique>
        </soapenv:Header>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <v011:lireVoie>
                <v011:CODE_COMMUNE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/max:InvokeLIREVOIE/max:LIREVOIESet/max:VOIE/max:CODE_COMMUNE"/>
                </v011:CODE_COMMUNE>
                <v011:CODE_VOIE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/max:InvokeLIREVOIE/max:LIREVOIESet/max:VOIE/max:CODE_VOIE" />
                </v011:CODE_VOIE>
            </v011:lireVoie>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```